# How to determine the first and last item in a list of objects in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a class `Person` (in Python) that implements the comparison operator such as `<` to compare their names.

I need to ask the user for input of 10 names and generate 10 `Person` objects. I need to determine the `first` and `last` person among them and print them. I got the class, operator and ask for user input. All is working but I am not sure how to determine the first and last person? Any help would be appreciated, below is my code:

```
class Person():

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.name)

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.name == other.name
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.name < other.name

#create empty list to hold person object
persons =[]
for p in range(0,10):
    if p==0:
        name = input("please enter name: ")
    else:
        name = input("please enter another name: ")
    #take user input and create 10 person object
    persons.append(Person(name))

for person in persons:
    print(person)
```

Comment: What do you mean "determine first and last person among them and print them"?

Comment: sample output:

please enter name: Mary
please enter another name: Lora
please enter another name: Keith
please enter another name: Brooke
please enter another name: Rebecca
please enter another name: Ramona
please enter another name: Pete
please enter another name: Shirley
please enter another name: Marian
please enter another name: Erik


first:  Erik
Last: Shirley

Comment: Why is Brooke not the first name in that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the comparison operators, you can use `max` and `min` to find the greatest and smallest `Person` objects.

```
persons = [Person('Bob'), Person('Charlie'), Person('Dee'), Person('Alice')]

print(min(persons).name)  # Alice
print(max(persons).name)  # Dee
```